# Can Unity 2D be used to make pixel-art games?

Tags: 2d, unity, sprites, pixel, pixel-art

I'm looking at the new 2D features introduced in Unity 4.3, and I think I might be missing something.

To me it looks like they are designed for high-res 2D games, where scaling the sprites is ok, but it is unsuitable for pixel-art games.

A pixel-art sprite is designed to be displayed exactly 1:1 pixels on the screen: scaling destroys it (linear up-scaling is an exception, i.e. you may scale it 2x, 3x, 4x etc.).

However I've found no way to "just display it as-is", apparently Unity insists in scaling it to whatever resolution it sees fit: I may control the Camera.size parameter, and the "pixels to units" parameter of the sprite, but I didn't manage to obtain this result.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, "Organ Trail" game was made entirely on Unity3d, before 4.3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This article](http://gamasutra.com/blogs/JoshSutphin/20130519/192539/Making_2D_Games_With_Unity.php) gives some useful explainations, even if that's before 4.3 came out:

> If you’re going for the “pixel art” look then the camera’s
>   orthographic size is of critical importance; this is the trickiest
>   part of nailing 2D in Unity.
>
> The orthographic size expresses how many world units are contained in
>   the top half of the camera projection. For example, if you set an
>   orthographic size of 5, then the vertical extents of the viewport will
>   contain exactly 10 units of world space. (The horizontal extents are
>   dependent on the display aspect ratio.)
>
> Recall that your sprite quad is 1 unit to a side. That means the
>   orthographic size tells you how many sprites you can stack vertically
>   in the viewport (divided by 2).
>
> To render the pixel-art look cleanly, you need to ensure that each
>   pixel of the sprite’s source texture maps 1:1 to the viewport display.
>   You don’t want source pixels being skipped or doubled-up, or your
>   sprites will look distorted and “dirty”. The trick to ensuring this
>   1:1 ratio is to set an orthographic size that matches your vertical
>   screen resolution divided by the pixel height of a sprite.
>
> Let’s say you’re running at 960x640, and you’re using 64x64 sprites.
>   Dividing the vertical screen resolution (640) by the pixel height of a
>   sprite (64) yields 10, the number of 64x64 sprites that can be
>   vertically stacked in 640 pixels. Remember that the orthographic size
>   is a half-height, so your target orthographic size in this case is
>   going to be 5 (one-half of 10). It should look like this:
>
> If you set your orthographic size to half or double that target you
>   may still get usable results, because the sprite’s vertical size will
>   still divide evenly into the viewport’s vertical size. But if you set
>   the orthographic size incorrectly, you will see some pixels skipped or
>   doubled, and it will look very bad indeed:
>
> **Variable Resolution**
>
> You don’t need to be confined to a single, fixed resolution in order
>   to render clean pixel art. **The simplest way to handle variable
>   resolutions is to attach a custom script to your camera which sets the
>   orthographic size according to the current vertical resolution and a
>   known (fixed) sprite size**:

```
// set the camera to the correct orthographic size
// (so scene pixels are 1:1)
s_baseOrthographicSize = Screen.height / 64.0f / 2.0f;
Camera.main.orthographicSize = s_baseOrthographicSize;
```

> While that is a simple fix, it does have a drawback: as the screen resolution
>   decreases, you’ll see less and less of the world, and sprites will
>   take up more and more of the screen. That’s the consequence of keeping
>   a 1:1 ratio between source and screen pixels: a 64x64 sprite takes up
>   more apparent space at 640x480 than it does at 1920x1200. Whether this
>   is a problem or not depends on the needs of your specific game.
>
> If you want your sprites to remain the same apparent size regardless
>   of screen resolution, then simply set the orthographic size to a fixed
>   value and leave it there regardless of the screen resolution. The
>   drawback there is that your sprites will no longer have a 1:1
>   source-to-screen pixel ratio. You can mitigate the ill effects of that
>   by only allowing resolutions which are exactly half or exactly double
>   your target resolution.

*(some emphasis added)*

This obviously works better if the height resolution is divisible by the sprite size, but even when it isn't, it still gives a good approximation of a decent result.

---

**TL;DR**: `cameraSelf.orthographicSize = screenH / (float)spriteSize / 2f;`

Comment: Another useful thing is to set texture filtering to 'Point'.

Comment: @Felipe good point: I forgot about that because I already figured it out.